# Count Occurence and Compute the Sum of Positive Number Until 0 is Reached in Racket

Tags: racket

Create a Racket procedure compute_pos that reads numbers from the keyboard until 0 is read, count how many positive numbers are read, and also compute the sum of only positive numbers, and display the count and the sum of positive numbers in different lines. Note that 0 is not included in the computations.

For example, if user enters:
3
6
-4
12
15
-9
-24
4
-3
-5
1
0

then your procedure should print

positive count: 6
positive sum: 41

You need to utilize “display” procedure to display the count and the sum, and also utilize “read” procedure to keep reading the next number from the keyboard.

I don't even know where to start so thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]  and read the information guides in the help center [help]. Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some research effort on your own (Google and StackOverflow searches), (2) learn what are appropriate questions for this forum, (3) show your images and (4) provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem

Comment: You can use `filter` using the `positive?` predicate to get a list of only positive numbers from a list of numbers. On that list, you can use `length` to compute the count and you can `apply` the `+` function to get the sum.

Comment: Thank you so much haha starting to make sense now